# Mac OS X Terminal - While True Do - Can you stop automatically under desired conditions?

Tags: mac, terminal, python

Currently I am using a following command: while true; do python [file]; sleep X; done

I was wondering if I can stop the loop if the result prints a word that I'm looking for.

Plus is it possible to make a sound when it stops?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the execution by entering the command `break`.

To make a sound, `tput bel` should work on most shells.

Something like the following example should work:

```
while true
do
     commands...

     if [[ "$YOUR_VARIABLE" == "value" ]]
     then
         tput bel
         break
     fi
done
```

Comment: That `if whatever` part is a big unknown though -- the OP wants to stop on finding a word in the output from `commands...`.